# Sort in Elasticsearch Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to sort a query with Query DSL java.

```java
Query query = NativeQuery.builder()
.withQuery(query)
.withSort()  --> here
```

```json
"sort": [
    {
        "estoques.preco": {
            "order": "asc",
            "nested": {
                "path": "estoques",
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "estoques.filial": "21"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I'm using

- Elastic: 8.12
- java: 17
- Spring: 3.1.3

How can I convert the json to a `withSort` with lambdas?